# Google map and places api exceeded your request quota for this API

Tags: javascript

i have create website on 000webhost. i use map on it and create new google api key but issue is that when i hit the api for first time through message exceeded your 'request quota for this API' how ever i never hit it before i hit the api for the first time with new api key. this is my php script.i need help

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('show_map'), {
        center: {lat: 33.6518, lng: 73.1566},
        zoom: 13
    });

    var input = document.getElementById('shopadd');

    var options = {
        types: ['(cities)'],
        componentRestrictions: {country: 'pk'}
    };

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);

    // Bind the map's bounds (viewport) property to the autocomplete object,
    // so that the autocomplete requests use the current map bounds for the
    // bounds option in the request.
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    // Set the data fields to return when the user selects a place.
    autocomplete.setFields(['address_components', 'geometry', 'name']);
    autocomplete.setOptions({strictBounds: true});

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
    infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        marker.setVisible(false);
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
            // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
            window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
            return;
        }
        var location = "Address " + place.formatted_address;
        location += "Latitude " + place.geometry.location.lat();
        location += "Longitude " + place.geometry.location.lng();
        var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
        document.getElementById('lat').value = lat;
        var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
        document.getElementById('lng').value = lng;

        // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
        }
        marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        marker.setVisible(true);

        var add = '';

        if (place.address_components.length>0) {
            add = add.concat(
                (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),' ',
                (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),' ',
                  (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || ''),' ');
        }
        document.getElementById('add').value = add;
        infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
        infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
        infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = add;
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
    // Autocomplete.
}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="my key"&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google changed their pricing model. The new plan gives you more flexibility and control over how you use our APIs. You can use as much or as little as you need and only pay for what you use each month.
As of July 16, 2018:

- The Google Maps Platform APIs are billed by SKU.
- Usage is tracked for each Product SKU, and an API may have more than one Product SKU.
- Cost is calculated by: SKU Usage x Price per each use.
- For each billing account, for qualifying Google Maps Platform SKUs, a $200 USD Google Maps Platform credit is available each month, and automatically applied to the qualifying SKUs.

For more information, visit this [Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing)